# How to enable stage 0 in webpack config to enable the decoratorPattern in a fluxible component

Tags: webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-2016, fluxible

I tried following the directions for using a decorator pattern in a fluxible connectToStores example

http://fluxible.io/addons/connectToStores.html

```
@connectToStores([FooStore, BarStore], (context, props) => ({
    foo: context.getStore(FooStore).getFoo(),
    bar: context.getStore(BarStore).getBar()
}))
class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div/>;
    }
}
export default Component;
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error on the @ symbol.  Do I have to configure or load something first in order for the decorator pattern to be recognized in my fluxible app?

I've tried the following webpack.config.js to enable stage 0 support on the fluxible template but I get an error saying I cannot declare query when there are multiple loaders

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './client.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./build/js'),
        publicPath: '/public/js/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    require.resolve('react-hot-loader'),
                    require.resolve('babel-loader')
                ],
                query: {stage: 0}
            },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'}
        ]
    },
    node: {
        setImmediate: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'eval'
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Comment: FYI, decorators are not part of ES6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up Babel with stage 0 support: http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_register

Comment: couldn't find the instructions in the doc, but I did find this link http://jamesknelson.com/unlocking-decorators-and-other-es7-features-with-webpack-and-babel/ which suggested putting  `query: {stage: 0} ` in webpackConfig.module.loaders but now I get error `Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list`